# Need help extracting xpath - R

Tags: r, xml, xpath

I'm trying to make a table from HTML content. I've made an example HTML doc to show exactly what the issue is - so although there are many easier ways to accomplish what I'm asking in this example, I have to do it this way (make separate vectors) given the actual larger HTML doc I'm dealing with.

Basically I need to extract specific values from top rows and bottom rows in a weirdly formatted table. Sometimes, however, there aren't values available in a specific row/column (not even dummy blank values), so I can't setup a table because variables are different lengths.

Example:

```
library(XML)
library(rvest)
htmlEx <- read_html(
  '<table>
    <thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr class="top">
          <td class="price">
            <span class="data-value"> 150 </span>
            <small class="name"> Good1 </small>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bottom">
          <td class="price">
            <small class="name"> Good2 </small>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="top">
          <td class="price">
            <span class="data-value"> 130 </span>
            <small class="name"> Good3 </small>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="bottom">
          <td class="price">
            <span class="data-value"> 180 </span>
            <small class="name"> Good4 </small>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </thead>
  </table>'
)

htmlEx <- htmlTreeParse(htmlEx, useInternalNodes=T)

topVals <- trimws((xpathApply(htmlEx, paste('//*[contains(@class, "top")]//span', sep = ''), xmlValue)))
topNames <- trimws((xpathApply(htmlEx, paste('//*[contains(@class, "top")]//small', sep = ''), xmlValue)))

bottomVals <- trimws((xpathApply(htmlEx, paste('//*[contains(@class, "bottom")]//span', sep = ''), xmlValue)))
bottomNames <- trimws((xpathApply(htmlEx, paste('//*[contains(@class, "bottom")]//small', sep = ''), xmlValue)))
```

Since there isn't a data-value for the first "bottom" (for Good2), `bottomVals` is of length 1 so I can't compile a dataframe.

Ideally I'd like to change my xpathApply search so that if there is no `<span>` under `<td class="price">` then it would show up as NA or "". My actual HTML has around 50 different rows with about 5-10 different values missing in different rows/columns, so I can't clean it with logic such as "if length `bottomVals` != length `topVals` then append an NA" because every day the order of missing data changes.

Is there a relatively easy fix to my xpath search to accomplish this, or will I have to change my approach completely?

EDIT:

My desired output would for this example is for `bottomVals` to be [NA, 180], as there is no value for the first class="bottom". This way I can combine everything into a dataframe (`data.frame(topNames, bottomNames, topVals, bottomVals)`) since they're all of length 2. And to generalize, is there a way to look for a specific element and have it be NA if it doesn't exist. E.g. if I tried looking for a `div` instead of `small`/`span` I'd get `[NA, NA]`.

I know this seems like a roundabout way to turn it into a dataframe, but it really is the easiest way given the actual DOM I'm working with (it's very unorganized and I have to do lots of data cleaning before compiling).

Comment: Would rvest's table function help? `html_nodes(htmlEx, "table") %>% html_table()`

Comment: In this example yes and that's usually my go to, but in my actual problem the DOM is setup so strangely that `html_table()` doesn't work. My current method has worked for years, but they recently updated their site to get rid of the `<span>` element instead of leaving it blank.

Comment: I think this could be straight forward, but I am not understanding which rows of the table you are looking for. Can you clarify what information you are looking to extract out. Given the sample above what is your desired output?

Comment: @Dave2e sorry about that, updated my post with the desired outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution using just rvest.  When the html/xml structure is missing some nodes, the easiest solution is to find a node common to every data point in interest.

In this case the "tr" row is common.  From there the using `html_node()` function will return a value for every parse node even if the subnode of interest is absent.

```
library(rvest)
#find all tr nodes
tablerows<- html_nodes(htmlEx, "tr") 

#parse each tr node and obtain the span value, name value and class
spanrows <- html_node(tablerows, "span") %>% html_text()
smallrows <- html_node(tablerows, "small") %>% html_text()
rowclasses <- tablerows %>% html_attr("class")

df<- data.frame(class = rowclasses, Names = spanrows, Values =smallrows)
df

   class Names Values 
1    top  150   Good1   
2 bottom  <NA>  Good2   
3    top  130   Good3   
4 bottom  180   Good4
```

This table can then reshape to the final desired form.

```
library(tidyr)
df$id = rep(1:(nrow(df)/2), each=2)
pivot_wider(df, id_cols=id, names_from=class, names_glue = "{class}_{.value}", values_from = c(Values, Names))

# A tibble: 2 x 5
id top_Values bottom_Values top_Names bottom_Names
<int> <fct>      <fct>         <fct>     <fct>       
    1 " Good1 "  " Good2 "     " 150 "    NA         
    2 " Good3 "  " Good4 "     " 130 "   " 180 "
```

Comment: @CoolGuyHasChillDay.  Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This will populate it with an empty string when the node is not present:

```
convert_empty <- function(x) {
  value <- xpathApply(x, './span/text()')
  if (is.null(value) ){ return ('') }
  return (xmlValue(value[1]))
  }
bottomVals <- trimws((xpathApply(htmlEx, paste('//*[contains(@class, "bottom")]/td', sep = ''), convert_empty)))
```